# Date Comparison Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I wanna compare date in linq query.i m going to get from date and todate as parameter in function and depend on that criteria query should fetch record lies between those dates.how to do this?

Comment: var result = from TDetail in dc.tbl_Customer_BillTransactions
                     join Cust in dc.tbl_Customer_Masters on TDetail.CustTrans_CustId equals Cust.Cust_Id
                     where TDetail.CustTrans_AgentId == AgentId && TDetail.CustTrans_PaidDate >= FromDate && TDetail.CustTrans_PaidDate <= FromDate
                     select new TransactionHistory

Comment: its giving error >= operator can not be used between string and system.datetime

Comment: @DharaPPatel: It sounds like you're trying to compare a *string* and a date, given that your database schema is broken. In future, please give more information in the question - see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to use them in the obvious way:

```
public IQueryable<Record> FindRecords(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    // Adjust accordingly
    return context.Records.Where(x => x.FooDate >= fromDate &&
                                      x.FooDate < toDate);
}
```

If you tell us more about the problems you're seeing when you try simple comparisons like the above, we may be able to help more.

Comment: i tried var result = from TDetail in dc.tbl_Customer_BillTransactions
                     join Cust in dc.tbl_Customer_Masters on TDetail.CustTrans_CustId equals Cust.Cust_Id
                     where TDetail.CustTrans_AgentId == AgentId && TDetail.CustTrans_PaidDate >= FromDate && TDetail.CustTrans_PaidDate <= FromDate
                     select new TransactionHistory

Comment: @DharaPPatel: That's using FromDate twice, and not using ToDate.

Comment: @DharaPPatel: And are both `CustTrans_PaidDate` and  `FromDate` indeed `DateTime` types?

Comment: @Jon - i changed that to todate but when i run this web service, this method giving me an error that : The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

Comment: @Jorik - CustTrans_PaidDate is Database field and its varchar in the table and FromDate and ToDate are two parameters i m passing to my web method as datetime

Comment: @DharaPPatel: you should have said before that the type is odd in the database. If it's meant to store a date, it shouldn't be a varchar. Fix your schema if at all possible.

Comment: actually i have to insert date like 10.02.2011 10:05:00 in the database so i have to keep it as varchar

Comment: @DharaPPatel: No you don't - that's just a DateTime as far as I can see. Why wouldn't you store it as that? If you're not even keeping it in a *sortable* format, you've got really big problems trying to perform this sort of comparison. Your query will have to parse *every row of the table* as a DateTime, on every query like this you perform.